# Как создать свой интерфейс для RX?

Tags: java, android, rxjava

```
Observable.create(subThread -> vkRequest.executeSyncWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            subThread.onNext(response);
            subThread.onComplete();
        }

        @Override
        public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int totalAttempts) {
            subThread.onError(new Exception());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VKError error) {
            subThread.onError(error.httpError);
        }
    })
```

Как создать интерфейс и добавить туда весь код который находиться в методе create?

А затем новый интерфейс использовать в create? Как правильно это сделать?

Так как я данный кусок кода буду использовать в более чем 30 классах, Чтобы потом проблем не было я вот решил использовать 1 интерфейс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно создать не свой интерфейс, а наследника от `VKRequest.VKRequestListener`:

```
public static class MyRequestListener extends VKRequest.VKRequestListener {

    private final ObservableEmitter subThread;

    public MyRequestListener(ObservableEmitter subThread) {
        this.subThread = subThread;
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        subThread.onNext(response);
        subThread.onComplete();
    }

    @Override
    public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int totalAttempts) {
        subThread.onError(new Exception());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(VKError error) {
        subThread.onError(error.httpError);
    }
}
```

А затем его использовать:

```
Observable.create(subThread -> vkRequest.executeSyncWithListener(new MyRequestListener(subThread)));
```

Comment: Что - то у вас код не правильный. Можете исправить? 

Как может быть ObservableOnSubscribe == Subscriber ?

Comment: @EraNewGames спасибо, исправил

Comment: А почему нету subThread.onComplete();? пишет `Cannot resolve method 'onComplete()'`

Comment: Мне кажется вся проблема в том что нету ObservableEmitter. Оттуда и вся проблема?

Comment: Обновил ещё раз

Comment: Воо спасибо работает))